# .val() returns empry strings when i try to fetch value of input in modal

Tags: html, jquery, forms

my `.val()` is not working
here is my code

```js
function validate() {
  var username = $('#username').val();
  console.log(username);
  var userEmail = $('#email').val();
  var password = $('#password').val();
  var cpassword = $('#cpassword').val();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="signupForm" id="signupForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="forUserName">User Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter User Name" aria-describedby="helpId">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="forEmail">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="signupemail" id='signupemail' class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email" aria-describedby="helpId">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" aria-describedby="helpId">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="forConfirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Confirm Password" aria-describedby="helpId">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="validate();">signup</button>

</form>
```

Comment: share your html code. console.log spelling is not correct.

Comment: Is that code inside an event handler that runs after the user fills in the input?

Comment: When you run your `username=` code, what does this give you?  `console.log($("[id=username]").length)`?  If you have *two elements* with id=username, then `$("#username")` will *always* give you the first, which will probably not be the one on the dialog (or it might be on a different dialog)

Comment: If not, it's getting the value when the page is first loaded, and it won't have anything filled in yet.

Comment: the label attribute for and input id should match. Please share full code to confirm what fires the fetching of username. Is the form loaded after page is rendered. can you share console.log($("#usersname").length)

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene right idea, but `console.log($("#username").length)` will always be 0 or 1.  If there's two (eg one on the main page and one on the dialog) it will still be 1, not 2.

Comment: When you click your button, does the page just flash and reload?

Comment: put type="button" in button tag (@j06891) and console.log($("#signupForm #username").length) (@freedomn-m)

Comment: @j08691 / Barmar - how would that affect the validate() code?  This would still run as the onclick= runs before the button submit/post

Comment: @freedomn-m the code will indeed run. And the page reloads, now showing anything unless you preserve the console between refreshes.

Comment: @j08691 so you think "returns empty strings" means "console is empty" ... I guess...  could do with more details from a very silent OP...

Comment: Actually console is return empty string but alert is showing the values i put on inputs i guess i may be missing something